# Observable fromEvent do not activate detectionChange on angular

Tags: angular, observable

I have been trying to solve this problem for days:
I'm doing an application that uses angular and electron, so I'm always in the production environment in angular.
I use electron's ipcMain and ipcRender to communicate between the main process and the render to display csv files.
The problem is that creating an observable fromEvent does not seem to trigger the angular changeDetection.
Initially I solved the problem using ChangeDetectorRef but this creates strange behavior on the material components.
To be sure not to make a mistake I copied the code from the tour of heroes application, if the observable is of ([1,2,3]) everything works... if I change the origin of the observable in fromEvent it doesn't work anymore.

the sercvice:

```js
export class PresetService {

 constructor(private electronService:ElectronService){}

  read() {
    this.electronService.ipcRenderer.send('read_presets');
  }

  getPresets():Observable<Preset[]> {
    //return of([1,2,3,4]) //this works
    this.read()
    return fromEvent(this.electronService.ipcRenderer,'preset_res').pipe(
      map(_=>_[1]),
      tap(_ => console.log('fetched presets',_))//in the log i see an array of preset objects
    );
  }

}
```

the component

```js
export class PresetsComponent implements OnInit {

  public presets:any[] //already tried to use observable here and ngFor with async pipe and the behavior was the same
  selected = new FormControl(0);

  constructor(private presesetService:PresetService/*, private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef*/ ) {

  }
  
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getPresets()
  }

  getPresets(): void {
    this.presesetService.getPresets()
    .subscribe(presets => {
      this.presets = presets
      //this.cdr.detectChanges() //if i add this i see all presets but material tabs do not works properly
    });
  }

  addTab(selectAfterAdding: boolean) {
    this.presets.push(new Preset());

    if (selectAfterAdding) {
      this.selected.setValue(this.presets.length - 1);
    }
  }

  removeTab(index: number) {
    this.presets.splice(index, 1);
  }

}
```

and the template

```html
<div>
  <button mat-raised-button
          class="example-add-tab-button"
          (click)="addTab(selectAfterAdding.checked)">
    Add new Preset
  </button>
  <mat-checkbox #selectAfterAdding> Select preset after adding </mat-checkbox>
</div>

<mat-tab-group [selectedIndex]="selected.value"
               (selectedIndexChange)="selected.setValue($event)">
  <mat-tab *ngFor="let preset of presets; let index = index" [label]="preset.ID">
    Contents for {{preset.ID}}

    <button mat-raised-button
            class="example-delete-tab-button"
            [disabled]="presets.length === 1"
            (click)="removeTab(index)">
      Delete Preset
    </button>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Comment: One problem I can see is that you are returning from the `getPresets` function before you call the `this.read()` to force the read. That may solve your problem. But... not sure. I just know that your `this.read()` call is never firing based on that code. You need to move the `this.read()` line of code to be before you return. Otherwise, it will never execute. Once you return, all remaining code doesn't get executed.

Comment: Oh sorry.. I was wrong when I copied the code here, i fix it right away

Comment: In your `subscribe` callback in the `PresetComponent`, what happens if you add the line of code `NgZone.assertInAngularZone()`. When you call that, if you are NOT in the zone, it will error. If you are in the zone, all will work. I suspect you aren't in the zone, for some reason.

Comment: It will error! So i tried to wrap this.presetService.getPresets() in ngZone.run() but it still error

Comment: Are you in the zone before you call `this.read()`?

Comment: Yes... i solved wrapping in ngZone.run only the this.presets = presets assigment

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved wrapping the assignment in ngZone.run()

relevant code:

```js
getPresets(): void {
      
    this.presetService.getPresets()//wrap at this level do not solve the issue
    .subscribe(presets => {
      this.zone.run(()=>{
        this.presets = presets //wrapping only this solve the issue
      })
    });
    
  }
```

thanks frosty for the hint!